# Cutting shallow-angle bevels with a circular saw - is it possible?

Tags: cutting, jig, circular-saw, bevels

Is there a way in which I can make shallow-angled bevel cuts using my circular saw?

I am wanting to create something such as this:
[image]

I have seen this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HH_-Lzheaow), but I'm not entirely sure what is going on.

I am very aware that this is relatively easy using a table saw and a vertical jig, however I do not have access to something like this :-(

Comment: I immediately thought of how cavalier we used to be about radial arm saws. https://youtu.be/AHRwN99fGCY

Comment: More seriously, that video link you provide shows how a track saw can be used to make a bevel cut. So, yeah. If you have a track saw, or can turn your saw into a track saw using a home-built or store-bought jig, you _might_ be able to do this.

Comment: Are you seeking to do this on a regular basis or just for a current project? There are other ways of approaching the problem than sawing. Especially if you're only bevelling long-grain surfaces this is bread and butter work for hand planes.

Comment: @Graphus - This would be a one off for the time being, and this would be done on the MDF project we have spoken about before :-)

Comment: It occurs to me we should ask how you intend to use these bevels. Is it just decorative or a feature, or are you using it as a gluing edge? It matter because the former can allow for a lot of variation, while the latter will need to be more precise.

Comment: I'd want to do this by plane, but you'd need to have the plane(s) already and be proficient in their use so for a one-off it's not really a viable solution. A jig as suggested in @fred_dot_u's Answer may feel like overkill but it's possibly the only way to do the cut with any sort of safety using a circ saw. You do need a suitable workbench or stout table to mount the jig to, for stability, presume you're covered there?

Comment: @jdv - Yes this is purely decorative.

Comment: @Graphus - I'll see what I can come up with ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're likely aware, cutting beyond the 45° limit of the saw can be challenging. It's necessary to think more vertically than usual.

Consider to build a fence that includes a 90° bracket along the entire length (or as needed to provide stiffness) that will permit you to place the angle as desired:

[image: 90° fence build]

Blade represented in red, circular saw plate is yellow, vertical work placement allows for single light blue cleat, while horizontal work placement requires additional darker blue cleat.

Picture the circular saw running along the top of the image with the blade set to match the desired bevel and depth. If the bracket is the right width (narrow enough), it could be used as the guide fence for the circular saw by attaching an additional guide piece to the underside of the saw.

If the work piece is too large to be vertical and the guide bracket is cut narrow enough, the attachment to the circular saw could be L-shaped and hook over the back side of the bracket.

Comment: How would this fence be used? I think the OP said they don't have a table saw.